# Connecting a HTPC with a TV in a different room

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, htpc, hdtv, chromecast

I am using a HTPC to watch movies on an older plasma TV (LG 60PK990, built in 2010). For this purpose I am using:

a) a wired connection via HDMI cable from the HTPC to the TV
b) a wired connection from the audio output of the HTPC to a Denon DRA-F107 stereo receiver + stereo speakers
c) a Logitech K400 Plus wireless keyboard and mouse
d) The HTPC runs Windows 10 and for playback I use MPC-HC with madvr and some custom settings

The problem is that the PC is also used as an office machine in a different room, so every time I want to watch a movie, I have to carry the case to the room with the TV (15 m further away).

I am looking for a solution, which solves this problem, so that I don't need to physically move the HTPC.

My questions are the following:

1) Is it possible to connect a device to the TV which will give me the possibility to use the TV as a monitor and at the same offer the feature of opening a remote session on the PC, so that I can start MPC-HC from the TV room? I have Ethernet LAN and Wi-Fi in both rooms.
Would Google Chromecast for instance do this job?

2) If there is such a device as listed under 1): Can I connect the Logitech K400 Plus or any other external keyboard/mouse combo to it? I still need some peripherals to control the playback.

Your input is appreciated! Also, if you know an easier solution, don't hesitate to tell me. Thank you!

Comment: I think you are " doing it wrong".. Do Windows file sharing on the PC and get a Kodi box.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the most expensive option? Of course, getting a second computer like the Nvidia Shield would do the job, but can't it be done cheaper?

Comment: Are you aware a Kodi box costs about US$50?

Comment: No. Which box are you referring to?

Comment: Kodi boxes are low power hardware (think something similar to a Raspberry Pi, etc.) with the open-source [Kodi](https://kodi.tv) "Home Theater" software installed on them. There are some third-party resources for these (i.e. people who build and sell them themselves) but you can use a guide like the following one to compare some DIY options - https://www.techradar.com/news/best-kodi-xbmc-streaming-boxes

Comment: Yes, but this would mean that the playback would run on the "Kodi box" and would be dependent of the hardware therein. If I want to play uncompressed blurays, then I will need better hardware, right? I already invested in my PC; investing alot of money in a second machine is not an option right now.

Comment: @Chris - what you are missing is that a truly uncompressed 1080p stream is about 7 gigabytes per minute - which is most likely more then your Ethernet can carry.anyway. I confess to not having a Kodi box (or Blu-ray drive for that matter) but I imagine that some Kodi boxes would be able to play ripped Blu-ray disks (provided the streams are decrypted). Kodi boxes have GPUs optimized for video playback.